# Make new same form on next last field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created the field on form html with press enter instead of tab, i want to make automatic create new same form when its enter in last field form

my problem : the form automatic created starting with the  second field, and the form always makes a multiple of 2 forms

expetation : created new same form once the user presses enter in the last field, and its just always 1 form only so on, and the select form follow the next new field form too.

Script

```js
var display = document.getElementById("area")

function tabE(obj, e) {
  var e = (typeof event != 'undefined') ? window.event : e;
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var ele = document.forms[0].elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
      var q = (i == ele.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
      if (obj == ele[i]) {
        ele[q].focus();
        break
      }
      display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        `<form method="" action="">
          <table>
            <td>1<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
            <td>2<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
            <td>3<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
            <td>4<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
            <td>5<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
            <td>6<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
            <td>7<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
          </table>
        </form>`);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<body onkeydown="javascript:if(window.event.keyCode == 13) window.event.keyCode = 9;">
  <div class="area" id="area">
    <form method="" action="">

      <table>
        <td>1<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
        <td>2<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
        <td>3<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
        <td>4<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
        <td>5<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
        <td>6<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>
        <td>7<br><input type="text" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"></td>

      </table>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you?

I fixed the HTML too

```js
const display = document.getElementById("area")
const table = document.getElementById("t1")
table.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.code == "Enter") {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (e.target.classList.contains("last")) {
      const row = table.querySelector("tr").cloneNode(true);
      row.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(inp => inp.value="")
      table.appendChild(row);
      row.querySelector("input").focus()
    }
    else {
      tgt.closest('td').nextElementSibling.querySelector('input').focus()
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="area" id="area">
  <form method="" action="">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="t1">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="last"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks mplungjan,  im trying your code with google and here, it doesn't work for, next field with enter and make a new form.

Comment: I make a new row if you press enter in the last field. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: yeah thats what i want, but im trying you code, its cant use enter for next field, and not appears new form on new row when tab/enter  in the last field

Comment: @mplungjan I think they still want [enter] in the previous fields to set focus to the next one.

Comment: @ITNewbie I removed the test for enter->tab and changed `.keyCode` to the recommended `.code`

Comment: okay i see @mplungjan.